# Access Tk frame created from loop

Tags: perl, foreach, tk-toolkit

I am creating a few Tk frames from an array. Each frame has a label and a status. The status is represented by the `background` option and the `$color` argument.

I have made the following example

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tk;

my $mw         = MainWindow->new(-title => 'test');
my $main_frame = $mw->Frame()->pack(-side => 'top', -fill => 'x');

my @array = ('M024','M016','M032','M066','M065','M044','M096','M099');

foreach my $example ( @array ) {
  Frame_creation($example, 'green');
};

MainLoop;

sub Frame_creation{
    my ($name, $color) = @_;

    my $exempleFrame = $main_frame->Frame()->pack(-side => 'left', -fill => 'x');
    my $exempleLabel = $exempleFrame->Label(-text => $name, -background => $color)->pack(-side => 'left', -fill => 'x');
}
```

Once the frame is created, how do I target the frame in the future if I desire to modify it with a `configure`?

Answer (score 2):

The handle `$exempleFrame` allows you to access the frame for modifying it via `configure`. You simply need to copy it somewhere so that you don't lose it when the subroutine exits

In your case you could have the subroutine return the frame handle

```
sub frame_creation{
    my ($name, $color) = @_;

    my $exempleFrame = $main_frame->Frame()->pack(-side => 'left', -fill => 'x');
    my $exempleLabel = $exempleFrame->Label(-text => $name, -background => $color)->pack(-side => 'left', -fill => 'x');

    return $exempleFrame;
}
```

and it could be `pushed` onto an array when you make the call

```
my @frames;

for my $name ( @names ) {
    push @frames, frame_creation($name, 'green');
}
```

You can then make calls like

```
$frames[4]->configure(-background => 'red')
```

to set the attributes of individual frames

This may be better done differently depending on how you need to access the frames (for instance, a hash relating the frame names to their handles may be useful) but this method will give you a simple collection of frame handles, which may be sufficient

#### Note

As you have written your code, each label completely fills and obscures its frame parent, so setting the background colour of the frame will have no visible effect

Here's a complete program that retains your red label background, but adds (external) ten-pixel padding around the label so that its containing frame can be seen

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow->new(-title => 'test');

my @names = qw/ M024 M016 M032 M066 M065 M044 M096 M099 /;
my @frames;

my $main_frame = $mw->Frame()->pack(-side => 'top', -fill => 'x');

push @frames, frame_creation($_, 'green') for @names;

$_->configure(-bg => 'red') for @frames;

MainLoop();

sub frame_creation{
    my ($name, $color) = @_;

    my $frame = $main_frame->Frame()->pack(
        -side => 'left',
        -fill => 'x',
    );

    my $label = $frame->Label(
        -text => $name,
        -bg   => $color,
    )->pack(
        -side => 'left',
        -fill => 'x',
        -padx => 10,
        -pady => 10,
    );

    $frame;
}
```

#### output

[image: Perl/Tk Example]

Comment: Thanks man that is exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for!


So my error was I was creating the frame not putting them into an array?


One further question I could ask is how I could modify a widgets within a frame using this system, I guess I have to push them too into an array? I'm confident I'll figure it out =)

Thanks again!

Comment: @mactírebeag: The problem is more that your frame handle `$exempleFrame` is local to the subroutine and is discarded once it has been created. Any way of saving those handles would suffice. Another way would be to get the list through the tree of widgets using `$main_frame->children`, but that would break if you added other independent frames to the main frame that weren't part of this "set". There are many ways to solve this, and the best way depends on the problem you are solving.